# Using user input as regex search expression

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a personal project that is designed to open a file specified by the user, then to take in user input and use that input as a regular expression to search the file with. The purpose of this is to gain a deeper understanding of how regular expressions work, and how to incorporate them into programs.

My problem lies in that all input the user gives me is formatted as a string. So (correct me if I'm wrong), an input of [a-z]+ will result in the search expression "[a-z]+". This is a problem if I want r"[a-z]+" as my search expression, as putting that in as user input will give me "r"[a-z]+"" (again, correct me if I'm wrong). This will obviously not work with regex. How do I format the input so that an input of r"[a-z]+" remains r"[a-z]+"?

This is the code section in question. The textFile in the function arguments is imported from another section of the program, and is used in the regex search:

```
def new_search_regex(textFile):
    """Query for input, then performs RegEx() with user's input"""
    global totalSearches
    global allSearchResults

    # ask user for regular expression to be searched
    expression = raw_input("Please enter the Regular Expression to be searched: ")

    # perform initial regex search
    foundRegex = re.search(expression, textFile)

    # if Regex search successful
    if foundRegex != None:

        # Do complete regex search
        foundRegex = re.findall(expression, textFile)

        # Print result
        print "Result: " + str(foundRegex)

        # Increment global total
        totalSearches += 1

        # create object for result, store in global array
        reg_object = Reg_Search(totalSearches, expression, foundRegex)
        allSearchResults.append(reg_object)
        print "You're search number for this search is " + str(totalSearches)        # Inform user of storage location

    # if Regex search unsuccessful
    else:
        print "Search did not have any results."

    return
```

Note: At the end I create an object for the result, and store it in a global array.

This is also assuming for now that the user is competently entering non-system destroying regex's. I will soon start adding in error checking though, such as using .escape on the user input. How will this affect my situation? Will it wreak havoc with the user including " in the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `r"..."` syntax is only useful to prevent the python compiler to interpret escape sequences (`\n` being converted to newline character for example). Once parsed by the compiler it will just be a regular string.

We you read input from the user with `raw_input the compiler does not perform any escape sequence interpretations. You don't have to do anything, the string is already correctly interpreted.

You can test this yourself like that:

```
>>> x = r"[a-z]+\n"
>>> y = raw_input("")
[a-z]+\n
>>> x == y
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly coming from the Python  http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html:

```
import re
m = re.search(regexp_as_string, payload)
m.group(0) #first occurence of the pattern
```

Comment: Remember to format your user input (in order to remove nasty end line characters).

Comment: Alternatively you could eval() the user's input but I wouldn't recommend it (even if you are dealing with a power user)